# CentOS and mutiple python website developers

Tags: centos, http, python

I need to be able to support multiple (~100) different users with their own websites on a CentOS based web server. They need to be able to use Python (v2&v3) along with Django. I understand that systemctl restart is required for apache, that can be arranged by a cron job. However, I have no idea as to the other tips & tricks and requirements from the admin side. Is there a website that will be use to me in setting up of the server? I understand that each of them can run their own web servers (simpleHTTPserver), but it looks very messy to me.

I would be grateful for any help regarding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using VirtualHosts and automating the setup

You can set it up to that `/var/www/<sname>` will automatically load for any `<sname>.domain.com`

Example: going to `s1.domain.com` and `s1.domain.com` will automatically load `/var/www/s1` and `/var/www/s2`, respectively.

### Nginx

The `server_name` directive is simply used to match a request to the site; you can use a regex:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(www\.)?(?<sname>.+?).domain.com$;
    root /var/www/$sname
    ...
}
```

You can use `$sname` throughout the rest of the config

### Apache

This is a little bit complicated but can be done

```
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
UseCanonicalName Off
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName vhosts.fqdn
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1+
</VirtualHost>
```

If you would like to use HTTPS, I'm sure there's an API to generate Letsencrypt certificates

Comment: The problem with Python comes from its virtual environment requirements. The above solution works for PHP, etc., but not adequate for Python.

Answer (score 0):

You should front their apps (Django, Flask, whatever pythonic) with a reverse proxy using Nginx.

Then install only the easy_install, setuptools and virtualenv packages in system python. All devs should use their own virtual env to install packages.